# wcf service not captured in fiddler 2?

Tags: wcf, fiddler, wcftestclient

still trying to record requests in fiddler 2 : (

i have created a simple WcfService1 in vs.net 2010 when I call it in wcftestclient.exe
it does not show up in Fiddler. Anyone any idea?

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
      <proxy bypassonlocal="False" usesystemdefault="True" proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888" />
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings />
    <client />
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: I don't see any WCF endpoints and WCF binding configurations in your config - where are they? If you want to make them point to a proxy, you need to specify that somewhere - and the `proxyAddress` in `<system.net>` probably isn't picked up by WCF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you address the endpoint using `localhost` as hostname? Use your machine name or network IP address since traffic to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` doesn't get captured.

Comment: using machinename now but it returns the error:Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible. Make sure your service is running and exposing metadata.